# azure - make 30 vnets with the same ip address range accessible to 1 vnet

Tags: azure, security, networking, vnet

I have

30 service fabric clusters in different vnets. 
Each of them has it own public load balancer and appliction gateway.
On each cluster there are 2 applications. app 1 which should be accessible from internet and app2 which should be only accessible to app 1
Unfortunatelly all vnets have the same ip address range.

1 vnet 'TestVnet' with couple of VMs which are created for testing purpose. Those are used to check all applications on each clusters.

Let assume that app2 accepts rest request on port 2000 (for every instanse of app2).

So what I want to achieve is to cut port 2000 on public LB, create internal LB on which port 2000 will be open to app1.

The problem is how to make port 2000 open for TestVnet ?

I thouhgt about using peering/vpn but it require that ip address ranges do not overlap
Changing Ip address range of vmss failed and cluster did not 'recover' after changes.
Using Network security group also failed. For security reason 'TestVnet' does not have public Ip address.

Question is it all possible to make all those service fabric cluster vnets available to TestVnet ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way Azure can solve this (in the present moment). to route traffic between vnets ranges need to not overlap. this includes user defined routes and network appliances.

You need to change your networking setup.